# Why are my notes not displayed/updated, even though reactjs received the data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, react-redux

I'm trying to load my notes from my Firebase database. Adding them goes fine and retrieving my notes is also fine (I can confirm that it's working via console and checking my firebase database by going to console.firebase.google.com).

I am using React-Redux for the first time on my project.

I already tried debugging and checking if the correct data has been shown by console logging the variables. Everything goes fine, however nothing is displayed or updated.

**App.js:**

```
componentWillMount(){
    const previousNotes = Array(0);
    this.removeAuthListener = app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        app.database().ref().child('notities').on('child_added', snap => {
            if(snap.val().username === this.props.email){
                console.log('DB_ADDED');
                previousNotes.push({
                    id: snap.key,
                    noteContent: snap.val().noteContent,
                    modifiedDate: snap.val().modifiedDate
                });

                console.log("previousNotes", previousNotes);
                store.dispatch({type: "DB_NOTE_ADDED", payload: { notes: previousNotes }});
        }
    });
```

**NotesBody.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class NotesBody extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <ul>
                {
                    this.props.notes.map((note) => {
                        return <li key={note.id}>{note.noteContent}</li>
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log("[STATE NOTESBODY]", state);

    return {
    notes: state.notes
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NotesBody);
```

**My reducer:**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { app } from '../config/config';

const initialState = {
    database: app.database().ref().child('notities'),
    notes: []
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log("Reducer running", action.type);

    switch(action.type){
        default:
            break;

        case "DB_NOTE_ADDED":
            console.log("DB_NOTE_ADDED", action.payload.notes);
            state = {
                ...state,
                notes: action.payload.notes
            }
            break;
    }

    return state;
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log("Store updated", store.getState());
});

export default store;
```

When my code has received the notes, it calls the dispatch function with the notes array in it:

```
var previousNotes = [
    { id: "1", noteContent: "Hoi" }
];
store.dispatch({type: "DB_NOTE_ADDED", payload: { notes: previousNotes }})
```

Actual result:

[image: Actual result]

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

EDIT: Added my action code. Now I only have 1 note loaded, if I implement the first solution below.

Comment: can you show your action code?

Comment: @ducmai Yes, see my post above. I edited it.

Comment: in your reducer I suggested to replace update notes with the following:                 notes: [...action.payload.notes]. I think your notes is not recognized as changed in your reducer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well shoot me in the face.. I managed to get it working in this way:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        notes: state.notes,
        notesLength: state.notes.length
    }
}
```

If I add something else than the length of the notes, the problem rises again.. What the..

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using some sort of loading state on that `NotesBody.js` component, just until you are sure your data is successfully stored. That being said add `loading: true` to your redux state, and only set it to `false` when you successfully get notes and update the state.

```
class NotesBody extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let notes = <p>Loading ...</p>;

    if (!this.props.loading) {
        notes = this.props.notes.map(note => (
            <li key={note.id}>{note.noteContent}</li>
        ));
    }
    return <ul>{notes}</ul>;
  } 
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log("[STATE NOTESBODY]", state);

  return {
    notes: state.notes,
    loading: state.loading
  };
}
```

And your switch should look like this:

```
switch(action.type){
    default:
        break;

    case "DB_NOTE_ADDED":
        console.log("DB_NOTE_ADDED", action.payload.notes);
        state = {
            ...state,
            notes: action.payload.notes,
            loading: false
        }
        break;
}
```

PS. Don't forget to switch loading to true when you decide to request new notes from your API.

Comment: I added your code. The data loads fine. I updated my post to show the results I have now.

Comment: So if I understand your "actual result image", I assume you only see last added note, right? You have to push your new note to the array of other notes in your redux state, add this to your state obj  "notes: state.notes.push(action.payload.notes)"

Comment: That does not work. It only loads the first note and when I implement your suggestion I get the error "this.props.notes.map is not a function"

Comment: See my answer below. Can you explain me why this is?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, I don't see you using that "notesLength" props in your component.